# Node.js file on AWS EC2 server just returns the contents of the file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I installed node onto an instance of AWS running ubuntu 14.04.
I made a file:

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer( function (req, res) {
    res.write('Hello world!');
    res.end();    
});

server.listen(3000);
```

When I access the file on the AWS server:

```
http://**.**.**.**/nodelearning/app.js
```

I just get the contents printed out, so I see this in the webpage:

```
'use strict';

var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer( function (req, res) {
    res.write('Hello world!');
    res.end();    
});

server.listen(3000);
```

I followed this site to install node(basically just a couple of commands) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

Cheers Vagrant

Comment: well your nodejs script seems to be in the public path of your web server, what you should really do is to run your nodejs script like 'node app.js' and then access it  http://**.**.**.**:3000

Comment: I ran node app.js and tried  http://**.**.**.**:3000     The browser timed out.

Comment: @Lonely_Vagrant make sure you got your 3000 port open in your ec2 security group

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution. I just needed to open the port. Can you respond as an answer so this question doesn't go unanswered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nodejs scripts runs by the node process itself, if you put a web server and make the node js scripts avalaible in the root folder, then the webserver will serve that file and you browser will proccess it as you have seen already.

You should run your script like this: `node app.js`

And in your case your backend will be at 3000 port, so access it through the browser(check the port is open before this).

Further reading: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html (uses express but it's the same example)

*see you space cowboy*